# example stand alone application using EJB-MDB, eclipse, jetty server?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, openejb

how to develop one example application using EJB-MDB, eclipse, jetty server? 
I have created two java class. and i have .jar file, where I have to deploy .jar file in jetty server? after that what I have to do?

Comment: jetty should work with OpenEJB, there is a would be (I did not check it myself) example on GitHub, https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-ejb (disclaimer: I don't know much neither about jetty, neither about the peculiarities of OpenEJB, just that it is a package which can be used to bring EJB functionality to servers which are not application servers).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement for EJB-MDB seems to demand a full blown server like Jboss, Glassfish, TomEE and others. If you need jetty with the equivalent of EJB MDB functionality probably you should look at Spring-Boot. On the other hand if you need EJB/MDB compatibility you should probably choose an Application server and each of these comes with a plethora of examples and quickstarts, but each one comes with it's own Servlet Container respectively Undertow, Tomcat, Grizzly, but  not Jetty.